# Residual Power in Decoupling Capacitors

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, discharge

I'm working on a battery powered prototype and have discovered an annoying bug. When power is removed from the device by disconnecting the battery, the voltage on the 5V power rail will decay fairly quickly to around 2V but then will decay much slower. In fact, it will stay between 2V and 1V for around 30 seconds. If the device is restarted during that time (i.e. the battery is reconnected), one of the chips will go into a bad state and the device will malfunction. This is especially annoying because this is precisely how most people power-cycle the device.

I figure that there is still residual charge being stored in the decoupling capacitors on the 5V power rail, which is causing the device to sit in this range for a while until parasitic resistances slowly drain the capacitors. Could this be correct?

If so, is there a generally accepted way to best discharge those decoupling capacitors?

Comment: Bleeder resistor.

Comment: Can you add details on the failure so it can be analyzed for a solution?  I understand if not, then you can examine a null current sensing active shutdown that works down to 0.6V

Comment: I can understand a bleeder R may not give a desirable battery effect on life, and contact bounce still poses a threat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you described is very typical for devices with low-power CMOS ICs. This is called "brown-out" conditions.

One simple solution is to add so-called "bleeding resistors" to power rails that cause the trouble. But in this case you will waste some power during normal operations, which might be prohibitive from battery life standpoint.

More expensive solution (used in portable electronics/laptops) is to use active circuits (typically FET transistors) on power rails. The transistors  are controlled by a voltage monitor, which turns the FETs on when some main voltage rail drops below certain limit, and the FETs discharge the rails quickly.

Some voltage regulator ICs have a built-in "[auto-discharge" circuitry](http://www.e-devices.ricoh.co.jp/en/products/product_power/ap_note/vr03.html).

In many cases it is sufficient to provide a robust hardware reset to CMOS IC after the brown-out condition, if IC has a well designed hardware RESET which overrides any residual "bad" states after Vdd is restored.

Comment: May be worth mentioning external voltage supervisors as an option if the IC doesn't have good builtin brownout protection.

Comment: Actually, I don't know any chips that even have any brownout protection. Usually ICs specify min-max voltage conditions that OEM product manufacturers must meet, otherwise functionality of IC can't be guaranteed. It is usually a product design responsibility to meet these conditions and eliminate brownouts. Reason is that brownout is difficult to formalize, and therefore difficult to test for.

Comment: The majority of microcontrollers have it - it's typically just an integrated voltage supe tied to the reset line.  But I guess most discrete logic does not.

Comment: I guess manufacturers of micro-controllers who really care about customers do include build-in BO protection. But many don't. Even sometimes a hardware reset is not really a reset, unfortunately :-(.

Comment: -1  "brown-out" is from AC line load regulation errors. ...not the OP's.  It is from abrupt battery disconnect then reconnect before Caps decay

Comment: I see no reason to split hairs about what is brownout and what is not. From the OP's device point of view, it's power gets interrupted and goes into intermediate ("brown") state. So it is a brownout condition for the device electronics.

Comment: "brown" refers to dim AC lights, in this case the device is removed form the battery and no lights.  It's unconventional to create new meaning to standard terms.

Comment: For a kitchen-wife, dimming of lights is true, but for a seasoned designer of digital and analog electronics the term is widely used as "a significant drop in the power supply output voltage."  http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/brownout-reset  So disconnecting a battery does constitute "a significant drop" of its output. Period.

Comment: YOur link only refers to AC line brown effects on DC power and not battery operated units disconnecting and reconnecting. Sorry I can't agree.  So are you suggesting a low input short circuit solution in this problem?

Comment: @TonyStewart "Brownout" is most definitely used to refer both to out-of-spec AC line voltages and, separately, DC supply droops as mentioned by Ali Chen in this answer.  e.g. http://www.scienceprog.com/microcontroller-brown-out-detection/ It's a very common issue in the design of small battery-powered electronic devices.

Comment: I do no doubt the term is misunderstood and misused. But the temporary loss of DC due to AC brownout and load regulated DC supply dip or intermittent DC contacts have entirely different root cause.  I have worked over 40 yrs in aerospace, power grid , telecom, computer design and test, in 3 continents and never once was this term misused as it appears to be here. but that's just my experience

Comment: Of course a "brown-out detector might serve multiple uses, generally DC OK signals are used to enable equipment, computers and battery operated devices and we would not consider a portable device to ever experience the root cause of a AC grid brownout condition but a line powered unit may experience this and the design may or may not be similar depending on details.

Comment: @TonyStewart: you know Tony, unfortunately things do change over time. For example, how do you like the term "shield" which kids are using today for add-on (or "piggy-back") boards?

Comment: that's ok. It's like cloud charges (+/-V)  and cloud servers (+/-$) It is also the reason I could easily understand Japanese Engineers and their schematics due the consistency in definitions and drawing standards, no matter which company... Shindengen, Fujitsu, Hitachi, Toshiba. They used Kanji or a phonetic writing to mimic the english words and meanings

Comment: @TonyStewart 
_"I do no doubt the term is misunderstood and misused. But the temporary loss of DC due to AC brownout and load regulated DC supply dip or intermittent DC contacts have entirely different root cause."_  - Yes, they are not the same thing, but they have the same name.  [It's not unusual for two concepts to share a name!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy)  And it's not being misused or misunderstood, we're talking about an common industry term used in datasheets and [textbooks](https://books.google.com/books?id=kcHBAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA291&dq=brownout+detection).

Comment: I have yet to read one where root cause was not an AC source.

Answer (score -1):

revised....

On my PC I know if I press the power down, it will not reset all the circuits unless I wait 20 seconds or press the reset switch which presents a load to decay the charge faster in <1 second. Often a reset is detected by the positive change in voltage and if not sufficiently decayed, it cannot produce a positive reset when the cap is still charged with a pull down resistor.   Although it is not destructive like you indicated in your situation,  It prevents my full power on reset (POR) function.

But let's examine your real problem with a potential scenario.

> "one of the chips will go into a bad state and the device will malfunction"

With LDO's and multiple supply voltages power sequencing can be is important to prevent CMOS latchup.

This can occur say when a logic chip powered perhaps by an LDO which all have common collector or drain type pullup regulators.  Say the output is still holding a charge to activate a logic chip which interfaces with another chip which is powered by say 5V. Even if it accepts 3V logic but cannot accept inputs > 0.7V above the supply rail otherwise it biases a substrate SCR latch and causes the chip to short circuit when the  5V supply power is reconnected.

Although this is hypothetically true, it may not be the user's exact scenario.

Such a problem is usually handled by putting a Schottky diode in reverse across the LDO to not only protect the LDO but pull down by the output within a diode drop to prevent latchup on other interface chips using the higher input rail.